# cannot find required auxiliary files: config.guess config.sub compile missing install-sh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, makefile, riscv

I am building the risc-v environment on a brand new Ubuntu (22). The last step is run .`/build.sh` but I got this:

```
cannot find required auxiliary files: config.guess config.sub
compile missing install-sh
```

What should I do?

Comment: Wrong forum, try askubuntu.com instead, if you're just using some software (it's unclear). This one here is about programming. If you intend to ask a programming question, please first take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Those files are provided by the autoconf package so you probably need to install that.  You may also need to install automake and maybe some other packages.  Isn't there a README or INSTALL or some type of instructions with the package telling you which utilities you need to build it?  Often these packages are intended to be downloaded as source tarballs which already contain all these files.  Only people who are actively developing the package would check out the Git (or whatever) repository directly.